# write scaling postgresql

Tags: postgresql, scaling, postgresql-9.2, hstore

i have a very write centric application that uses postgres hstore. my typical work flow is a `SELECT` followed by a number of `UPDATE`s or `INSERT`s (mostly the former). This happens at typically around 500 'tasks' a second.

so my single postgres instance just can't cope. i see that the postgres server is cpu bound and the postgres processes are `UPDATE`ing all the time. Disk I/O appears fine and i have plenty of memory free (44GB out of 48). i've tried tuning as per [postgres's wiki page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) and pg_tune, but i just need a bit more performance.

my tables follow the following design:

```
   Column   |           Type           |                              Modifiers                              | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                            | plain    |              |
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                            | plain    |              |
 context    | hstore                   | default hstore((ARRAY[]::character varying[])::text[])              | extended |              |
 data       | hstore                   | default hstore((ARRAY[]::character varying[])::text[])              | extended |              |
```

and nearly all of my `UPDATE`s are of the type:

```
UPDATE <table> updated_at=<date> WHERE id=<id>
```

upon digging, i've found two projects that claims to help with write performance:

- [postgres-xc](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/)
- [postgres-r](http://postgres-r.org/)

which would you recommend for my (rather simplistic) workflow?

(and yes, i have tried mongo, however, i miss the query schematics of SQL)

Comment: I think postgres-r is not really finished yet - definitely not production ready. So that leaves you with postgres-xc. Other options might be Bucardo or PL/proxy (which is basically a "manual" sharding through PL/pgSQL)

Comment: Try asking on the [pgsql-performance](http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/) list, you will get more detailed hints for your specific case. But you have to provide more detailed info also, rather than simple “just can't cope”.

Comment: Details please. `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` of relevant queries, and show a typical batch with `SELECT` and subsequent updates. In general, try to reduce round-trips, try to do more in the DB, and do fewer bigger transactions.

Comment: In addition to Craig's questions, please add hardware details.  How many processors?  What type?  How many cores?  Hyperthreading?  This is particularly important when looking at questions of parallelism and CPU-bound performance.

Answer (score 4):

First, I think you need to be a lot more specific.  Performance tuning is very fact-centric and without a lot of details (explain plans, etc), information on your hardware, etc. we can't tell you what to do.  Additionally something like Postgres-XC adds a lot of complexity although it does help with write performance.  I think it would help in your case but you really want to optimize what you have (and maybe hire someone to optimize it for you) first.

There are however a bunch of warning signs in your post (which is another reason I think hiring a professional might be a good idea).  Without knowing more I can't tell you whether Postgres-XC is the right solution or not.  What I can tell you is you will have a steep learning curve implementing it.

So I want to go through the warning signs because they represent possible tuning points.

1. `i see that the postgres server is cpu bound and the postgres processes are UPDATEing all the time.`  This is most likely caused by too much contention for semaphores and shared memory.  You are likely to find that if you reduce your max connections you will process more per second.  A connection pool might help.
2. All your interesting data is on extended storage.  This means extra random disk I/O on storage and retrieval.  Unless you are doing a lot of sequential scans on the tables, you should let PostgreSQL decide what to TOAST.
3. I call baloney on your claim that most statements are like `UPDATE <table> updated_at=<date> WHERE id=<id>` since there is probably very little reason to record a row as updated when you aren't updating the data.  Something else is likely going on here.  My guess is that you have a lot of queries updating stuff in extended storage too.  This may not be a big deal performance wise since you are not I/O bound but it does incur overhead with both CPU and disk I/O.

On the whole Postgres-XC is a great project and I would recommend it.  However it adds a lot of complexity to the database and if you can make your single instance work, you are likely to find that is a lot cheaper to run in the long run (simplicity is golden).